# Rails: how to run all migrations up to a certain timestamp

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I'm trying to revert my database to a previous state. For some reason `db:rollback` isn't working properly (I might have flubbed one of my `down` methods), so instead of rolling back, I was wondering if I could get there by dropping the database and then re-running certain migrations. Essentially, I'd like to run `db:migrate`, but I'd like it to stop at a particular timestamp.

Is there a rake command that will run all migrations up to and including a given timestamp?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
rake db:migrate VERSION=timestamp
```

Comment: Ah. I didn't realize that ran multiple migrations. Thanks!

Comment: "rake db:migrate:up VERSION=timestamp" will run the single migration.